# OpenSSL causing very slow Rails boot time on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, openssl

I'm having a problem with Ruby on Rails running extremely slowly. I'm using Ruby 2.1.3p242 and Rails 4.2.1 on a Windows 8 machine.

Whenever I run anything that requires rails to boot (including tests) it takes a long time to get up and running. I put some calls to Benchmark in config/environment.rb on a clean install of rails:

```
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)
User cpu    System Cpu   Total Cpu   elapsed time
0.000000    0.000000     0.000000    (0.000000)

Rails.application.initialize!
15.282000   2.891000  18.173000 ( 18.201173)
```

Clearly `Rails.application.initialize` is taking an absurdly long time considering its a clean install.

Thanks in advance for your help

Edit-1: I'm running on a dual core i3 4010u@1.7GHZ with 4gb of RAM. I don't think my machine is too bad as it runs most things very well.

Edit-2: I ran `ruby-prof` on `Rails.application.initialize` and found the culprit. A process was taking up 85% of the run time:

```
<Module::SecureRandom>#random_bytes
<Module::OpenSSL::Random>#random_bytes
```

This is apparently occuring in `Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/securerandom.rb#62`
I looked up line 62 in that file and this is what I found:

```
return OpenSSL::Random.random_bytes(n)
```

So anyone have any idea what this means?

Comment: My only guess is either your machine sucks or it's a Windows related issue. All i can suggest is using [ruby-prof](https://github.com/ruby-prof/ruby-prof) to try and track down the culprit. Even on powerful machines Rails takes a few seconds to initialise.

Comment: maybe you have spring disabled?

Comment: Spring will only speed up subsequent loads...

Comment: According to the spring Github page: _"Spring makes extensive use of Process.fork, so won't be able to provide a speed up on platforms which don't support forking (Windows, JRuby)"_

Comment: If you are using ActiveRecord, it reads meta data about the tables mapped to all of your model's when the app first boots up. If the connection to the database is slow then the boot times for Rails will be abysmal.

Comment: @GregBurghardt It's a fresh installation of Rail so there are no instances of ActiveRecord yet.

Comment: Use bumbler to see your load times... Then, well, let's take it from there after that... https://github.com/mark-ellul/Bumbler

Comment: @RubyRacer I already used ruby-prof, please see my second edit in my post.

Comment: Oh, I see... Have you openssl propertly installed on your system? https://www.openssl.org/related/binaries.html

Comment: @RubyRacer I just installed openssl and am unfortunately getting the exact same delays

Comment: Are you using cygwin or anything like that or the regular windows cmd prompt?

Comment: Also, now that you've install OpenSSL on your system have you completely closed out of your cmd session? Maybe spring is running now and needs to be restarted so that binary is used?

Comment: @rainkinz I'm using console emulator (x64). Just tried it using the standard windows cmd prompt and the same issue is occuring.

Comment: @rainkinz Also yes I've closed my console after each attempt. I'm not sure that spring runs on windows machines, can't find it in the gemfile.

Comment: Some of my colleagues develop on Windows and it is pathetic how slow it runs.  An rspec suite that takes a minute on my Mac takes 20 on their machines.  I'm not saying Windows is not a viable Rails platform, but I've never seen it work well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Edit-2: I ran ruby-prof on Rails.application.initialize and found the
>   culprit. A process was taking up 85% of the run time:
>
> ```
> <Module::SecureRandom>#random_bytes
> <Module::OpenSSL::Random>#random_bytes
> ```

Yeah, the OpenSSL code for seeding the random number generator is problematic on Windows. See [Random Numbers and Windows Issues](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Random_Numbers#Windows_Issues) on the OpenSSL wiki.

---

> ```
> return OpenSSL::Random.random_bytes(n)
> ```
>
> So anyone have any idea what this means?

Ruby is returning random numbers. In this case, OpenSSL will autoseed itself before retuning random number with `RAND_poll` since no other seed was provided.

---

Ruby should *not* call `RAND_poll` or allow it to be implicitly called by the library. If the random number generator has not been seeded, then the library will automatically seed itself by calling `RAND_poll` internally.

Rather, Ruby should read bytes from the OS using [`CryptGenRandom`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379942%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and then call OpenSSL's `RAND_seed`. That will avoid the call to `RAND_poll`.

Comment: Thanks for that. I checked out the link on random numbers and windows issues and it suggested on this [page](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mailing.openssl.users/uEO5roA55Wg) I'm not sure how to go about doing what they suggest, which is to _"Comment out the following lines of code in RAND_poll():"_ How would I go about doing this, and is it a viable approach in your opinion?

Comment: @Joshua - Fix Ruby, not OpenSSL. Ruby is not using OpenSSL correctly, and it shows its head on Windows. In Ruby initialization, have it call CryptGenRandom and then pass those bytes to OpenSSL's RAND_seed. You should also file a bug report with Ruby because this is a problem with the platform.

Comment: I have no idea how I'd go about doing that. Is there any easy way of fixing this issue, or any guides you can point me in the way of?

Comment: *"Is there any easy way of fixing this issue..."* - I don't know since I'm not a Ruby hack (the language frustrates me because of all the hoops I have to jump through for basic security services. So I simply avoid it altogether). I'm fairly certain the fix is *not* comment out code related to the random number generator in OpenSSL. We know [how that ends](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2008/05/random_number_b.html).

Comment: @JoshuaHarris I'll just tag along to this answer, since it seems this issue has been resolved exactly as jww described in Ruby 2.3. See here: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12139

Answer (score 2):

Putting this in my `config/application.rb` (**before** `require 'rails/all'`) speeds up `rails s` by 10-15 seconds on windows.

```
require 'securerandom'
SecureRandom.hex(16)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been a windows rails dev for a while now. I have never solved this rails startup issue. Running a microsecond Rspec test takes rails 22 seconds to load on my PC.
When I (temporarily) comment out the line in securerandom.rb (all ruby versions) and replace it with a hardcoded return the startup time is reduced to 10 seconds.

```
#return OpenSSL::Random.random_bytes(n)
return "\xD3\x04F\f0\xD6{G\xB9\x81"
```

Comment: Oh and I have installed the latest versions of openSSL 1.02 and git. 2.7.x

Comment: The hack above is not a solution BTW. Bad things happened to my tests. they started failing when they had previously passed.