# Windows alternative to zeus and spring for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl

Just wondering if there's any viable windows alternative to using zeus and spring for ruby on rails. I have a very long startup time for my rails server due to a problem with openSSL (as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29984838/openssl-causing-very-slow-rails-boot-time-on-windows)). As far as I'm aware zeus and spring don't run on windows, and the only other alternative i could find was spork, which is no longer being maintained and from what I could gather doesn't run on Ruby 2.1 and rails 4.2.1 which is what I'm using

Any windows rails developers out there who can lend a hand?

Cheers.

Comment: Have you tested `spork` with your setup? You should tell bundler to take the latest version directly from github.

Comment: No I haven't I'll give this a go.

Comment: Also see [OpenSSL causing very slow Rails boot time on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29984838/608639). Its a Ruby platform bug because Ruby is not using OpenSSL correctly. Unfortunately, a bug report should be filed with Ruby, but I can't get the confirmation email from the bug reporter. (And OpenSSL is experiencing a bug, too. But OpenSSL's bug does not preclude Ruby from using the library correctly).

Comment: @lx00st spork did the trick perfectly, thanks for your suggestion :)

Comment: So...what do people use now that Spork isn't being maintained anymore?

TDD is a big hassle on Windows.

Comment: I bit the bullet and switched to linux, haven't looked back since!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use spork as alternative to spring https://github.com/sporkrb/spork