# Rails 5 very slow startup on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have installed RoR 5 in my laptop

- Windows 10
- SSD
- 4gb ram
- i5 5thgen

I started working on a project which i wanted to specificaly test under windows , and i noticed some lags and latency.

So i started a new rails app , to rule out my code , and the latency was the same.

I also tested `Webrick` and the latency is still there.

Im talking about `28 seconds` !!!

I know there are many relative issues but most talk about rails in earlier versions.

The main reason i wanted to program this app in rails , is to run in a local server , but the user has windows on his machine...

```
C:\Users\John\railstestapp\testapp>rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.0.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
```

Very big time gap here close to 25 seconds

```
*** SIGUSR2 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGUSR1 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGHUP not implemented, signal based logs reopening unavailable!
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.6.0 (ruby 2.2.4-p230), codename: Sleepy Sunday Serenity
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
```

as you'd expect this performance continues throughout the page..

Any ideas? am i missing something? any of you guys developing rails 5 on windows? any tips?

I also tested on my main machine

- 16gb low latency ram
- ssd
- AMD FX8350

same slow response , but a little faster than the laptop!

Also weird thing is that , if i run the rails console side by side , i see the rails log printed in the console , but the browser loads for a long time!

I thought it was a browser problem , so to rule that out , i browsed the site by another of my local machines , so i can only use the server and not the Windows browser... still no avail , the response time is really slow!

this is Puma on the fast machine

```
C:\Users\John\SimpleGym\simplegym>rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.0.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
*** SIGUSR2 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGUSR1 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGHUP not implemented, signal based logs reopening unavailable!
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.6.0 (ruby 2.2.4-p230), codename: Sleepy Sunday Serenity
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
DEPRECATION WARNING: after_filter is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1. Use after_action instead. (called from block (2 levels) in <module:ClassMethods> at C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:191)
DEPRECATION WARNING: after_filter is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1. Use after_action instead. (called from block (2 levels) in <module:ClassMethods> at C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:191)
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2016-10-03 18:59:54 +0300
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by SessionsController#index as HTML
  Rendering sessions/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Session Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "sessions".* FROM "sessions"
  Session Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "sessions".* FROM "sessions" ORDER BY "sessions"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "students" INNER JOIN "attendances" ON "students"."id" = "attendances"."student_id" WHERE "attendances"."session_id" = ?  [["session_id", 1]]
  Session Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "sessions".* FROM "sessions" ORDER BY "sessions"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Session Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "sessions".* FROM "sessions" ORDER BY "sessions"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Session Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "sessions".* FROM "sessions" ORDER BY "sessions"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Session Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "sessions".* FROM "sessions" ORDER BY "sessions"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "students" INNER JOIN "attendances" ON "students"."id" = "attendances"."student_id" WHERE "attendances"."session_id" = ?  [["session_id", 2]]
  Session Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "sessions".* FROM "sessions" ORDER BY "sessions"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendered sessions/index.html.erb within layouts/application (113.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 621ms (Views: 538.5ms | ActiveRecord: 8.0ms | Solr: 0.0ms)
```

this is webrick on the fast machine

```
C:\Users\John\SimpleGym\simplegym>rails server webrick
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 5.0.0.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
[2016-10-03 19:17:19] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2016-10-03 19:17:19] INFO  ruby 2.2.4 (2015-12-16) [i386-mingw32]
[2016-10-03 19:17:19] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=9936 port=3000
DEPRECATION WARNING: after_filter is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1. Use after_action instead. (called from block (2 levels) in <module:ClassMethods> at C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:191)
DEPRECATION WARNING: after_filter is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1. Use after_action instead. (called from block (2 levels) in <module:ClassMethods> at C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:191)
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2016-10-03 19:17:30 +0300
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by SessionsController#index as HTML
  Rendering sessions/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Session Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "sessions".* FROM "sessions"
  Session Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "sessions".* FROM "sessions" ORDER BY "sessions"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
   (1.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "students" INNER JOIN "attendances" ON "students"."id" = "attendances"."student_id" WHERE "attendances"."session_id" = ?  [["session_id", 1]]
  Session Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "sessions".* FROM "sessions" ORDER BY "sessions"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
   (1.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "students" INNER JOIN "attendances" ON "students"."id" = "attendances"."student_id" WHERE "attendances"."session_id" = ?  [["session_id", 2]]
  Session Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "sessions".* FROM "sessions" ORDER BY "sessions"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Session Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "sessions".* FROM "sessions" ORDER BY "sessions"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Session Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "sessions".* FROM "sessions" ORDER BY "sessions"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Session Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "sessions".* FROM "sessions" ORDER BY "sessions"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "students" INNER JOIN "attendances" ON "students"."id" = "attendances"."student_id" WHERE "attendances"."session_id" = ?  [["session_id", 3]]
  Session Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "sessions".* FROM "sessions" ORDER BY "sessions"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendered sessions/index.html.erb within layouts/application (135.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 679ms (Views: 596.3ms | ActiveRecord: 6.0ms | Solr: 0.0ms)



[2016-10-03 19:17:51] ERROR Errno::ECONNABORTED: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine. @ io_fillbuf - fd:8
        C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:80:in `eof?'
        C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:80:in `run'
        C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
[2016-10-03 19:17:51] ERROR Errno::ECONNABORTED: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine. @ io_fillbuf - fd:9
        C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:80:in `eof?'
        C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:80:in `run'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
```

Thank you all guys for trying to help me , i tried the solutions with no avail .. seems like rails just wont do it (yet?) ...

Nothing seems to provide a good development environment , i advised the client to use it online ..

// Update

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_flcE49VcE1ZmVPeTFuQjUyU2s/view

Im uploading a video showing this issue.

- **Update after trying Ruby 2.3**

There's a world of problems when you try to install ruby 2.3

- SSL errors about https://rubygems.org (you have to go http://)
- sqlite3 error 1 (path in rakefile)
- sqlite3 after fixing error 1 , error 2 presents an error about
  sqlite3 adapter.

Found no solution regarding error 2 and stopped trying...

maybe ill switch to PG , only to see if the performance is better and mark this as solved , this requires a bit of time , so ill do it when i have some :)

Thanks!

Comment: is this startup time? response time? hammer time? :)

Comment: 28 seconds after 'rails s'  is given in the console!  Response times are slow after that as you'd imagine...

Comment: slow startups times don't really matter - they're annoying, but they only happen once. Slow response times matter a lot more - because that actually impacts on system performance. Note: I'm not sure I can actually help you much. Mostly my response is "windows is like that"... :(
(others may have some ideas to help you though, so good idea asking)

Comment: Ahh.. I was afraid of that.. Ill try uploading some response times, as far as i remember it was close to 600 ms for a simple and light index page..also thanks so much for trying to help

Comment: 4GB of memory is pretty constrained, so you may be having issues there, especially as things like Chrome love to consume >2GB of it. Do you have another machine you can test on?

Comment: Oh yes i also tested it on my main workhorse FX3850, 16gb low latency ram,  ssd.  Its funny i didnt mention this machine but i thought the rails installation was wrong.  But now that the laptop failed too seems like the workhorse rails was ok after all..  In the fast machine it was *slightly* faster,  but still slow enough to prevent it from being a development environment..  (w7 on the fast machine,  same rails version!)

Comment: Sounds really strange. I tried a clean Rails 5.0.0.1 project on a Linux box with an old Intel Core 2 Duo, and I got both the console and server running in about 5 seconds. Are you including any special gems? What about your database, where is it running? Your problem sounds like it could be a DNS lookup issue. How does the CPU usage look like while you wait for 28 seconds? Is the CPU idle or doing stuff?

Comment: See my answer. This issue seems to have been fixed in Ruby 2.3. Update to 2.3 and it may solve your problem.

Comment: Same problem here folk. The only difference is that I'm running rails on WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux). It has been impossible to use Windows to develop a Ruby application since it takes 20sec to start or to run the specs. I've tried the same app on a Linux machine and it runs smoothly.

Answer (score 4):

One cause of the slow boot times could be OpenSSL.
See the discussion here:

[OpenSSL causing very slow Rails boot time on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29984838/openssl-causing-very-slow-rails-boot-time-on-windows)

Also read this answer for a possible temporary solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36629699/823617

Here's a Rails ticket discussing the issue:
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25805

According to this ticket, the OpenSSL issue has now been fixed in Ruby 2.3:
https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12139

Comment: Id say this is very likely the real issue here.

Comment: @frcake throw a comment on the rails issue and link back to this post, it's often good to highlight that things like this need looking into.

Comment: @Casper , thank you so much for taking the time to help me ! , i will do this tomorrow first thing ! , i did look around OpenSSL issues based on your answer, also did hardcode some random numbers , not the way this guy states though! Evolve , after checking this answer thoroughly , next thing is to link this to the ruby section , I also shared a video link that shows the issue, the app in the video is running perfectly fine in Ubuntu... Thank you guys so much.

Comment: `rake -T` takes 4.3 minutes for a project with Ruby 2.5.3 and Rails 5.2.2. `irb; require 'openssl'; OpenSSL::Random.random_bytes(256);` is immediate.

Comment: @Chloe you might want to open a new ticket for your issue on the Rails repo. Perhaps there is some other problem with Ruby/Rails on Windows too. Also it could be a good idea to run your project on a Linux machine (virtual or real) first, to verify if the slowness is indeed caused by Windows. Perhaps you did this already, but it was not clear from your comment.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked at this at all myself but you could potentially try using the new built in Ubuntu that's part of Windows 10.  It's in beta though so YMMV.  I would test it out by seein if you can firstly install a ruby version manager (like [rvm.io](http://rvm.io)) as if that runs your app is likely to run.

https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/03/30/run-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows

At least then you are much closer to a true posix style terminal.

Comment: Hmm thanks ill take a look at that first thing tomorrow and come back with feedback!

Comment: sadly no w10 from the customer , i think I'll stop searching for a solution , it seems like rails just wont do it , i followed a lot of tutorials etc etc but nothing seems to work.. Thank you for your time and effort! ill post what helped if i find an answer.. no luck with the Git desktop either :S

Answer (score 0):

If you are not on Win 10, I always found the default command line pretty average and not including many things taken for granted on other platforms.

I've found the easiest approach was to download github for Windows and use the configured terminal they provide. (Well they used to provide a terminal it's been a while since I've done it). Worth a try if the Ubuntu approach is a no go.

https://desktop.github.com

Comment: Standard Windows executable Ruby from the Windows Command Prompt still has `rake -T` taking 4.3 minutes with Ruby 2.5.3 and Rails 5.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to mention this one before, you could also try RailsInstaller http://railsinstaller.org/en it's by the folks at EngineYard and sets up a full rails env for you. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be under active Dev :/ (one plus, no-body is reporting speed as a problem in their github issues FWIW)

Yeah I know it's frustrating.

Just FYI, when I was doing Windows Dev previously I personally ended up installing virtualbox and installing Ubuntu on there, that worked fine for local Dev but yeah "install a virtual machine" isn't really the answer ur looking for and that was before most of these other options existed.

Comment: Thank you Evolve,  i *think* i did install my env with railsinstaller,  ill doublecheck tomorrow and let you know!  Thank you  very much!